# "MongoServerError: This node was not started with the replSet option" but it is

Tags: mongodb, windows

I installed MongoDB 4.2 on my Windows11 machine.
In cmd in admin mode i startet it with

```
mongod --config "F:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install
```

The config file:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: d:\mongo\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: d:\mongo\data\db
replication:
    replSetName: "rs0"
```

After the command the Server startet successfully.
I connected with

```
mongosh
```

But when I try to initiate the rplica set with

```
rs.initiate()
```

I Get the Error:

```
MongoServerError: This node was not started with the replSet option
```

But the replica set is set in the config, so can someone please tell me, what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
I changed to the version 4.4 now it works.